# Swift CoreData sortdescriptions not work

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I would like to get all sorted data from coredata, but its not works.
Here is my entity:

```
class Kurzus: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var kurzuskod: String
    @NSManaged var kurzusnev: String
    @NSManaged var kredit: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var felvett: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var teljesitett: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var jegy: NSNumber
}
```

Here is my func to get sorted data:

```
func getSortedData(entity: String, keys: [String], ascend: [Bool]) -> [AnyObject] {
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    for i in 0..<keys.count {
        let sd = NSSortDescriptor(key: keys[i], ascending: ascend[i])
        request.sortDescriptors?.append(sd)

    }
    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    return results
}
```

but i get an unsorted data...
I tried to sort data by "kredit" attribute:

```
println("=========================")
    let res3 = dbHandler.getSortedData(entity, keys: ["kredit"], ascend: [true]) as [Kurzus]
    for k in res3 {
        println("Kurzuskód: \(k.kurzuskod) \nKurzusnev: \(k.kurzusnev)\nKredit: \(k.kredit)\nFelvett: \(k.felvett)\nTeljesitett: \(k.teljesitett)\nJegy: \(k.jegy)")
}
```

But its not sorted, whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `request.sortDescriptors` is `nil`, so that the optional
chaining

```
request.sortDescriptors?.append(sd)
```

simply does nothing. You have to create an array first and then
append the sort descriptors:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
request.sortDescriptors = [] // <-- Start with empty array!
for i in 0..<keys.count {
    let sd = NSSortDescriptor(key: keys[i], ascending: ascend[i])
    request.sortDescriptors!.append(sd)
}
```

This can be also done more swifty using `map()`:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
request.sortDescriptors = map(0 ..< keys.count) {
    NSSortDescriptor(key: keys[$0], ascending: ascend[$0])
}
```

or with `map()` + `Zip2` (which creates a sequence of pairs
from the given arrays):

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
request.sortDescriptors = map(Zip2(keys, ascend)) {
    NSSortDescriptor(key: $0, ascending: $1)
}
```